# Typescript - string' is not assignable to type 'FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting the error below:

```
Type '(props: PropsWithChildren<{ amount: number; }>) => string' is not assignable to type 'FC<{ amount: number; }>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)
```

when using the below typescript function, not understanding the issue here, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Code is below,

```js
const MoneyAmount: React.FC<{amount : number}> = (props) => {
    return (
        new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
            style: "currency",
            currency: "USD", 
            maximumFractionDigits: 4
        }).format(props.amount))
}

export default MoneyAmount  ;
```

Comment: please use triple backticks if you want to embed the piece of code. See how I did it in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look on `FC` type:

```js
   type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

    interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
        (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
        propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
        contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
        defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
        displayName?: string;
    }
```

This function returns `ReactElement<any, any> | null`.

WHich in turn is  just a `jsx` with set of properties.

```js
    interface ReactElement<P = any, T extends string | JSXElementConstructor<any> = string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> {
        type: T;
        props: P;
        key: Key | null;
    }
```

All you need to do is to wrap your return value into a `span`:

```js
const MoneyAmount: React.FC<{ amount: number }> = (props) => {
  const text = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency", currency: "USD", maximumFractionDigits: 4
  })
    .format(props.amount)


  return <span>{text}</span>
}
```

Let's try to use it without `FC`:

```js
import React from 'react'

const MoneyAmount = (props: { amount: number }) => {
  return (
    new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD",
      maximumFractionDigits: 4
    }).format(props.amount))
}

// Its return type 'string' is not a valid JSX element.
const x = <MoneyAmount amount={42} />
```

Hence, `string` is just invalid JSX

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your string in `<Fragment>`, and it will pass typecheck.

The issue is that React is expecting a `ReactElement` type, and `string` isn't one of those. `Fragment` lets you return strings and arrays to components.