# I can't use useContext with Typescript with my react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I am new to typescript and trying to build a Todo app with the use of `'useContext'` hook using typescript-react.

I am not able to pass `TodoContextProviderProps` as a prop below, to my Provider function.

```
import React, { FC, createContext } from "react";
    import { ITodo, TodoContextInterface } from "../utils/interfaces";
    
    const TodoContext = createContext<TodoContextInterface | null>(null)
    
    type TodoContextProviderProps = {
        children: React.ReactNode;
    }
    
    export const TodoContextProvider: FC<TodoContextProviderProps> = ({children}) => {
    
        const todos: ITodo[] =[]
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
Type '({ children }: TodoContextProviderProps) => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<TodoContextProviderProps>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

Here are my Interfaces:

```
export interface ITodo {
    id: number;
    task: string;
    status: boolean;
}

export interface TodoContextInterface {
    todos: ITodo[];
    saveTodo: (todo: ITodo) => void;
    removeTodo: (id: number) => void;
}
```

Can you guys please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What does the body of component look like? Looks like you missed to return a `ReactElement`

Comment: I think this page will be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69187916/15318755

Answer (score 0):

Your component does not return anything. It literally tells you:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> |
> null'.

You forgot to return a react element.

Comment: Hey, first of all sorry i should have put the whole code, but I have returned this:


    return <TodoContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</TodoContext.Provider>

Comment: Can you please edit your question, I want to see your return there